# Getting Blank Activity not with existing Product Information while click on List View Item row in CartActivity

Tags: android, android-listview

I am writing a *Cart App*, and allowing user to **add items into Cart Activity**, in cart item list i am using *3 Textviews for numeric value (i.e: Item Cost, Qty, Total)* and these **values are coming from ProductInformationActivity.java**, now i **want to allow user to update** any of the item which is still in Cart Activity by click on that particular item, i want to open that item in *ProductInformationActivity.java* with existing details like: what Qty user has entered earlier (like: we see in Cart Apps), to do that i am using below code in my Cart Adapter....

```
     public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow_cart, null);
        vi.setClickable(true);
        vi.setFocusable(true);          

        vi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) 
        {   
            HashMap<String, String> item = Constant.wishProducts.get(position);
            Log.d("CartAdapter", "onClick :: " + item);
            Intent myIntent = new Intent 
            (activity, com.era.restaurant.versionoct.menu.ProductInformationActivity.class);
            Log.d("CartAdapter", "Intent :: " + myIntent);
            myIntent.putExtra("Item", item);
            activity.startActivity(myIntent);        
        }
    });
```

Comment: Post your logcat error. Are you using the `Listview` to display each items? How you are going to add the items ?

Comment: @Grishu i posted my Logcat....

Comment: Please post some more code so that someone can understand the implementation and find the bugs.

Comment: @ChulbulPandey You are getting NumberFormatException, when you are trying to convert non number string to double using `Double.parseDouble()` method

Comment: @Grishu i have posted more code

Comment: @Pragnani yes you are right i am getting problem in this line: itemamount = Double.parseDouble(text_cost_code.getText().toString()); please check my code of ProductInformationActivity.java and tell me what are the changes i need to do in my code

Comment: Do you enter the value in `text_cost_code` in floating point ?

Comment: Where have you set your layout in your activity ? As `setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);` ?

Answer (score 2):

Two things you can do:

First, only allow numeric data in your EditText field.

Second, ensure that you have not null value in your `EditText` with a simple check.

> ```
>   if(text_cost_code.getText().length() > 0)
>     {
>    try{
>         itemamount = Double.parseDouble(text_cost_code.getText().toString());
>      catch(NumberFormatException e)
>      {
>       }
>     }
> ```

Make sure you have defined the inputType as `number` or `numberSigned` in your `TextView` 
            `android:inputType="numberSigned"`

**EDITED:**

Try to get the String from your `Intent` in your `ProductInformationActivity` as below:

```
      String myItemValue = getIntent().getStringExtra("Item");
```

Comment: now i am not getting NumberFormatException, and able to open ProductInformationActivity.java but getting blank, in short not getting existing detail of an Item in ProductInformationActivity.java, I hope you can help me in this as well now see my code which i have written in getView() method in CartAdapter.java

Comment: it will not work for me @Grishu, i hope you are getting what i am trying to say? in ProductInformationActivity.java i want to show each and every detail of that item like: Name,Image,Description,Cost,Qty,Total everything buddy...need help

Comment: `but getting blank, in short not getting existing detail of an Item in ProductInformationActivity.java` What values are you trying to show in your `ProductInformationActivity` ? As in your CardAdapter `getView()` method you are only passing the item value in your intent but you are not trying to get that value from your intent.

Comment: I think if you want to show each details in your `ProductInformationActivity` then in this case you need to pass each values by intent from your CardAdapter class and then access that values in your `ProductInformationActivity` class from intent and then you can display that values as i have showned in my edited answer.

Comment: just check my updated question now, i believe that now you will find some way for me

Comment: From your screen shots i guess its and issue of your layout design. You are getting the values but your values are not properly displayed in your layout. Please check your layout design of `ProductInformationActivity` class.

Comment: layout is ok, as you can in my one of the screen shot Item Name: Samoa here i am getting everything ok, and this is the actual ProductInformationActivity.java view but once i do click on ListView Item row then i am getting that blank and bad layout..and i guess i am not getting value because i am not getting Item Name even in header text

Comment: I guess there is problem with your values only please try to debug the code and try to print each values in logcat and then check that whether u r getting all the details or not. If you get all the values then there'll be issue with layout only.

Comment: Hi @Grishu intent extra "item" is of type HashMap...Check the question once

Comment: @Pragnani Thnx for your hint dear.

Comment: You are passing the whole HashMap in your intent so you have to access each value of your `Item` by using the HasHMap only. You first get all the values of your Item in your HashMap and then try to access it by loop.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

You are sending `HashMap<String,String>` as a extra when click on list item.

You should get the HashMap extra and then get the product information from it.
like this

```
  HashMap<String,String> items=new HashMap<String,String>();
    if (getIntent().getSerializableExtra("item") != null)
    items = (HashMap<String, String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("item");

    String title = items.get(KEY_TITLE);
    String description = items.get(KEY_DESCRIPTION);
    String thumb_url = items.get(KEY_THUMB_URL);
    String cost = items.get(KEY_COST);
    String total =items.get(KEY_TOTAL);
```

---

this

```
  itemamount = Double.parseDouble(text_cost_code.getText().toString());
```

causing the `Exception`, because either `text_cost_code.getText().toString()` is not a `Number` or it is `empty`

You need to make sure that it contains `Number`, and is not empty.

then place this code in `try catch` if Exception caught then change the value to `0`

```
try{
 itemamount = Double.parseDouble(text_cost_code.getText().toString().trim());
}
catch(NumberFormatException e)
{
itemamount=0;
}
```

Comment: now i am not getting NumberFormatException, and able to open ProductInformationActivity.java but getting blank, in short not getting existing detail of an Item in ProductInformationActivity.java, I hope you can help me in this as well now see my code which i have written in getView() method in CartAdapter.java

Comment: just check my updated question now, i believe that now you will find some way for me'

Comment: @ChulbulPandey Hey sorry for late reply, I was busy with another work.. Let me know your problem?